# Why can't I insert this value using timestamp but can with datetime?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I want to insert this value: `2020-03-29 01:00:00`

If I set up a column called `date` with data type `datetime` I can insert the value. But if I use the data type `timestamp` I cannot insert and get an error message:

> Incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-29 01:00:00' for column 'date' at row 1

Furthermore, if I insert `2020-03-29 02:00:00` using data type `timestamp` it works... seriously, what is going on here?

I am using the GMT timezone. I'm creating a 2020 calendar table where I want to insert every hour in a year. Should I skip that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the daylight time-saving change. You're trying to insert an unexisting timeframe, so we can call it the daylight saving gap.

Solution: Just skip that specific time in your table.

Comment: What about the other time change?  When an hour repeats!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch every hour that exists, have a sequence of integers and do

```
x + INTERVAL y HOUR
```

Where x is some constant base time and y is the sequence of hours.  The result of the sum is a valid hour, suitably converted according to DST hours, leap years, etc.